# Ionic Serve not able to view the website on external devices on the same network

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, ionic-framework, ubuntu-22.04

I have a Ionic Website that uses React on Linux (Ubuntu Jenkins 22.04). I was at the initial phase of development so I had just generated a sample website using the prompt available when you use the ionic start command.
Once the sample code was created, I made a few minor adjustments in the Front-End and wanted to try and see if I can display the website on my other device, which is on the same network. When I tried doing so, it either shows ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT or ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE. The website is visible and working fine on the http://localhost:8100 and/or http://ip_address:8100 (after running with the --external command) but when I try to access it on other devices on the same network using http://ip_address:8100, it is giving me ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT or ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE error.

I tried

- Using ionic serve --external
- Using ionic serve --address 0.0.0.0 and Using ionic serve --host0.0.0.0
- Disabling firewall using `sudo UFW disable`
- Installing `npm install -g native-run` as suggested on [this page](https://eliteionic.com/tutorials/accessing-localhost-from-mobile-device-ios-android/)

I'm not sure what I can do in this case. I know that this is possible since a while back when I was working on one of my other project with Ionic React (on Windows), I had the same issue but it seemed to have auto resolved somehow and I was able to view the website on other devices on the same network so I didn't bother to look further into it, but it seems like I might be missing something here, maybe something with Ubuntu, or something else.